# HTTPResponse fail to display Japanese characters

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

When I set content type as

```
response.setContentType( "text/html" );
```

Japanese characters were displayed properly, but Japanese characters were missing when I set content type as "application/pdf".

I have also tried "application/pdf; charset=Shift_JIS", but didn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to create a PDF directly from a JSP file?

Comment: Yes, It report in PDF format

Comment: Are you creating the pdf yourself?  If so you may need to embed the Japanese fonts.

Comment: set SHIFT_JIS in the InputStreamReader

Comment: @Java1 I am using JasperReport's API to create PDF

Comment: Well, it would be better if you use a real PDF generator like iText or a report tool that generates PDF instead like jasper reports.

Comment: @JunedAhsan: but same InputStreamReader is working for HTML.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561929/jasperreports-fonts-issues-unijis-ucs2-h-japanese-converting-old-reports-t

Comment: Why shift_js and not UTF-8?

Comment: @JunedAhsan: Thank for link, but link has explained different problem

Comment: @fge: I have found it in some links :), I am trying it with UTF-8, will let u know the result

Comment: It is not working with UTF-8 also.

Answer (score 0):

PDF is a binary format, and should be handled by both the servlet and the user's web browser without doing any text-based character encoding and decoding.

So if characters are not being displayed correctly, the problem is either in the PDF itself (i.e. there is some problem with the way that it has been generated) or in the software that it displaying it.

It is puzzling that *just* changing the response content type is having this effect, because that should have no effect on the way that the response is created on the server side.  So I have two possible explanations for you:

1. You are actually changing *something else* in addition to the response content type.  If that is the case, you need to explain (better) what you are actually doing.
2. The content that you are trying to send is actually really HTML ... and when you set the response content type to PDF, you are causing the browser to send an HTML document to a PDF viewer.  (I'm surprised that you get anything at all when you do that.  I'd have thought that the browser-side PDF viewer would report a corrupted document or something.)

Comment: I have investigated and found that this issue is related to Jasper's PDF generation APIs, not with HTTPRespone.I will update proper fix, once I get it